# How to normalize the symmetrizer of a qudit state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-states, normalization

**Notations :**

1. $\mathcal{H}= \mathbb{C}^d \otimes \cdots \otimes \mathbb{C}^d$ where $\mathbb{C}^d$ appears $N$ times.
2. $S(\mathcal{H})$ is the symmetric subspace of $\mathcal{H}$.
3. $(|\epsilon_1\rangle,\ldots,|\epsilon_d\rangle)$ is a basis of $\mathbb{C}^d$.
4. $\mathbb{N}^N_d=${$k \in \mathbb{N}^N ~|~ k_i \leq d ~\forall i$}.

**Definition :**

1. Let $$ \widehat{S} : \mathcal{H} \rightarrow S(\mathcal{H}) $$
   such that $\forall |\psi\rangle=|\epsilon_{i_1}\rangle \otimes \cdots \otimes |\epsilon_{i_N}\rangle\in V$, with $i_j\in ${$ 1,\ldots,d $} $\forall j$, $$\widehat{S}(|\psi\rangle)=\frac{1}{N!} \sum_{\nu \in S_N} |\epsilon_{\nu^{-1}(i_1)}\rangle \otimes \cdots \otimes |\epsilon_{\nu^{-1}(N)}\rangle. $$ $\widehat{S}$ is the *symmetrizer* of a state.
2. Let $|\phi\rangle= \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}^N_d} c_k |\epsilon_{k_1}\rangle \otimes \cdots \otimes |\epsilon_{k_N}\rangle$ with $c_k \in \mathbb{C}~ \forall k\in \mathbb{N}^N_d$. $|\phi\rangle$ is a *normalized* state if $$\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}^N_d} | c_k|^2 =1.$$

**Question :**  $\widehat{S}(|\psi\rangle)$ is not a normalized tensor $\forall |\psi\rangle\in \mathcal{H}$. How should I modify the definition of $\widehat{S}$ to systematically obtain a normalized symmetric state ?

**Nota Bene :**  If one multiplies $\widehat{S}$ with $\sqrt{N!}$, it solves the problem if $|\psi\rangle= c_k |\epsilon_{k_1}\rangle \otimes \cdots \otimes |\epsilon_{k_N}\rangle$, but not if $|\psi\rangle= \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}^N_d} c_k |\epsilon_{k_1}\rangle \otimes \cdots \otimes |\epsilon_{k_N}\rangle$.

**For example**, you could take the state $|0\rangle \otimes (|1\rangle+ |2\rangle ) \otimes (|0\rangle + |2\rangle)$.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't the state $|\psi \rangle = |0\rangle \otimes |0\rangle \otimes |0\rangle $ get mapped to $\sqrt{6} | \psi \rangle$ if you replace the $N!$ by $\sqrt{N!}$? There will still be six terms in the sum as defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A symmetrizer $\hat{S}$ can't be a unitary operator (which is what you're asking for) because a symmetrizer is a projection operator onto a proper subspace $\mathcal{H}_S \subset \mathcal{H}$. This means that $\hat{S}$ will automatically map any vectors orthogonal to $\mathcal{H}_S$ to the zero vector, regardless of their normalization.

For example, the antisymmetric state
$$|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|0\rangle \otimes |1 \rangle - |1\rangle \otimes |0\rangle),
$$
will be mapped to the zero vector by $\hat{S}$ or any multiple of $\hat{S}$.  No normalization convention can make the norm of the zero vector non-zero, and so the norm of $|\psi\rangle$ can't be preserved under the action of a symmetrizer.

More generally, any vector $|\psi\rangle$ can be decomposed as the linear combination of a normalized vector $|\psi_S\rangle \in \mathcal{H}_S$ and a normalized vector $|\phi\rangle$ which is orthogonal to $\mathcal{H}_S$:
$$
|\psi\rangle = a |\psi_S\rangle + b |\phi\rangle
$$
The norm of this vector will be $|a|^2 + |b|^2$.  Applying $\hat{S}$ to this vector will then yield
$$
\hat{S} |\psi\rangle = \lambda a |\psi_S\rangle
$$
where $\lambda$ depends on the chosen normalization for $\hat{S}$.

You might think that we could just choose $\lambda = 1/a$.  But the problem is that $a$ differs from vector to vector, whereas the normalization of $\hat{S}$ is fixed by the definition of the operator above.  So, for example, if we pick the normalization of $\hat{S}$ to "work" for the vector $|\psi\rangle$ (i.e., $\lambda = 1/a$), then that normalization *won't* work for another vector
$$
|\psi'\rangle = a' |\psi_S\rangle + b' |\phi\rangle
$$
with $a' \neq a$.

Comment: Thank you for your very clear response. Could you please inform me whether there is a method to make this operator unitary, taking into account any state except antisymmetric ones?

Comment: @Baloo:  No.  See my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation !